# Eclipse Target Platform Bundle Cache location

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How does eclipse determine where do create the cache for a target platform? Maybe I didn't use the correct search terms to find anything in the documentation.

I have one workspace, where the bundles of the target platform are downloaded to and added to the Plugin-In Dependencies from
.metadata\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core.bundle_pool\plugins

And another workspace where they are downloaded to and used from
eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi<numbers>\data<numbers>\plugins

The second one is problematic. If I open another eclipse instance, the cache gets corrupted and an endless rebuild cycle begins in the previously opened workspace.

If I use the same target platform file, I still see above behavior. So it seems to be something about the workspace.

Comment: Are there any differences in the Target Platform configurations between the two? What do the contents of the xxx.target file look like?

Comment: It's not the target Plafrom file. Sorry. forgot to mention this. If I use the same file, I still see above behavior.